# Find the minimum value of: $\dfrac{a}{b+3a}+\dfrac{b}{c+3b}+\dfrac{c}{a+3c}$

Tags: inequality, summation, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a,b,c>0$, find the minimum value of: $$\dfrac{a}{b+3a}+\dfrac{b}{c+3b}+\dfrac{c}{a+3c}$$

I have tried:

$\bullet$ The minimum value is $\dfrac{3}{4}$ occur when $a=b=c$

$\bullet  \dfrac{a}{b+3a}+\dfrac{b}{c+3b}+\dfrac{c}{a+3c}= \dfrac{a^2}{3a^2+ab}+\dfrac{b^2}{3b^2+bc}+\dfrac{c^2}{3c^2+ca}\ge\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+ab+bc+ca}=\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3(a+b+c)^2-5(ab+bc+ca)}$

$\bullet$  $ab+bc+ca\le\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$ so we have $\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3(a+b+c)^2-5(ab+bc+ca)}\le \dfrac{3}{4}$ but we need to prove $\dfrac{a}{b+3a}+\dfrac{b}{c+3b}+\dfrac{c}{a+3c} \ge \dfrac{3}{4}$

Can you give me some hint ?

Comment: The minimum value is definitely not $\frac 34$. Even trying $a=1,b=2,c=3$ confirms this. In fact, for *every* combination of $a,b,c$, the quantity I'm getting is below $\frac 34$. Can you confirm that $\frac 34$ is the *maximum*, and not the minimum value? In fact, the minimum looks, to me, to be $\frac 13$ by using some combinations.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon $1/3$ is not a minimum, it is an infimum for the expression, a value never reached.

Comment: @user Good point, in my calculations I did not conclude that $\frac 13$ couldn't be attained, hence I used the word minimum in a loose fashion. I now see your answer, and +1!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes I supposed so! I’ve pointed out that to avoid confusion by the asker or readers. Thanks

Comment: This result is not corret.

Comment: @ZAhmed Yes, the first bullet point is incorrect. It turns out that $\frac 34$ is in fact the *maximum* of the given expression, and the infimum(not minimum) is $\frac 13$ as the answer below explains.

Answer (score 5):

The value $\frac 3 4$ is a maximum, indeed we have that by $x=\frac b a$, $y=\frac cb$, $z=\frac a c$ with $xyz=1$

$$\dfrac{a}{b+3a}+\dfrac{b}{c+3b}+\dfrac{c}{a+3c} = \dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3} \le \frac 3 4$$

and

$$\frac34-\left(\dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3}\right) =\frac{3 x y z+ 5 y z+ 5 x z+ 5 x y+ 3 x + 3 y  + 3 z-27}{4 (3 + x) (3 + y) (3 + z)}\ge 0$$

since by AM-GM

$$3 x y z+5 y z+ 5 x z+ 5 x y+ 3 x + 3 y  + 3 z \ge 27\sqrt[27]{(xyz)^{18}}=27$$

with equality for $x=y=z=1$.

As noticed the expression has not a minimum, indeed by

- $b=ka \implies x=k$
- $c=kb \implies y=k$
- $z=\frac1 {xy}=\frac1{k^2}$

we obtain

$$\dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3}=\dfrac{1}{k+3}+\dfrac{1}{k+3}+\dfrac{k^2}{1+3k^2} \to \frac13$$

as $k \to \infty$ and

$$\dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3}-\frac13=\frac{53 + 9 (x+y+z)}{3 (x + 3) (y + 3) (z + 3)}>0$$

which shows that the value $\frac13$ is an infimum for the expression that is

> $$\dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3}>\frac13$$

Comment: On the contrary if find $a/(b+3a)+b/(c+3b)+c/(a+3c)=13/18=.7222$ for $a=1, b-2, c=3$

Comment: @ZAhmed It says $a,b,c. > 0$

Comment: Sorry they are 1,2,3; actually.

Comment: I agree with Ahmed. I'm not sure how your AM-GM applies, EG What did you do with the denominator?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes you are right! It was a wrong attempt. I rolled back to the previous!

Comment: We can get much smaller value than 3/4.  EG $a = 1, b = x , c = x^2$, and let $ x \rightarrow \infty$ gives us $\approx 1/3$, so your approach is definitely wrong.

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm showing the reverse inequality for the maximum indeed.

Comment: @CalvinLin I've completed the dsicussion adding your useful insight! Hope now is a complete proof also for the infimum. Thanks

Comment: You have not proven that it is the infimum. You have only shown that the greatest lower bound is at most 1/3. Why can't it be smaller for some other selection for values?

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry I was suspended for a day and I wasn't able to reply. I'm afraid and sorry in advance for the possible naive or stupid question, but why show that the limit at $1/3$ and that $\dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3}-\frac13>0$ do not suffice to conclude that $1/3$ is the infimum? Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: @CalvinLin Doesn't $$\dfrac{1}{x+3}+\dfrac{1}{y+3}+\dfrac{1}{z+3}-\frac13=\frac{53 + 9 (x+y+z)}{3 (x + 3) (y + 3) (z + 3)}>0$$ prove that the expression is greater than $1/3$ in all the cases? It seems obviuos to me. Sorry but I can't yet get the point. Also the answer by Michael seems to confirm that.

Comment: @CalvinLin They cancel out. The term $xyz$ survives but it is equal to 1.

Comment: Ah ic. Then I misinterpreted you and your solution is correct.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for your patience! Indeed I’ve made some confusion while solving the problem and presenting the result. I’m glad now it is clear! Regards

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

We know that our expression is closed to $\frac{1}{3}$ but
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+3a}\geq \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{3b+3a+3c}=\frac{1}{3}$$ and we got the same result again.

Comment: Oh very nice. I think this was the solution that I saw many years ago, but forgot.

Comment: @Calvin Lin  Yes, it's known trick.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This seems so simple in this way!

Comment: (+1) but what does the phrase "closed to $\tfrac13$" (which occurs in all your answers) mean?

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley  For $c\rightarrow0^+$ we have $\frac{a}{b+3a}+\frac{b}{c+3b}+\frac{c}{a+3c}\rightarrow\frac{a}{b+3a}+\frac{1}{3}$ and for $b\rightarrow+\infty$ we have $\frac{a}{b+3a}+\frac{1}{3}\rightarrow\frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: I wasn't asking for a proof that the expression has $\tfrac13$ as a limiting value. (That was already clear to me.) I was asking for the meaning of a form of words that I haven't previously seen used in a mathematical context.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

We know that the expression is closed to $\frac{1}{3}$, but by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+3a}=\frac{a^2}{ab+3a^2}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3a^2+ab)}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3a^2+6ab)}=\frac{1}{3},$$ which says that $\frac{1}{3}$ is an infimum.

Answer (score 0):

For $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $b\rightarrow+\infty$ we see that our expression is closed to $\frac{1}{3}$.

But $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+3a}\geq\frac{1}{3}$ it's just $$\sum_{cyc}\left(9a^2b+\frac{53}{3}abc\right)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Hi @Michael, can we say that $\sum_{cyc}\left(9a^2b+\frac{53}{3}abc\right)>0$ and that $1/3$ is an infimum? Thanks

Comment: @user Yes, of course. It's infimum. Because we showed before that the expression is closed to $\frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: Thanks, my question is related to the objection received by @CalvinLin but I can't get the point of his argument.  I'm always trying to learn something on inequalities but they are really brain breaker! Thanks again, Bye.